# Fetch dropdown values or id from an inline grid

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I want to fetch dropdown values or IDs. I am using a dropdown control in an inline editing kendo grid. I'm trying to obtain the values using the change function. My demo code is:

```
function gridEdit(e)
{
    griddata = $('#CodeConfiguration').data("kendoGrid");
    codeType = e.container.find(":input[name=CodeType_032]");
    fixedCode = e.container.find(":input[name=FixedCode]");
    alert(codeType.id);
    codeType.change(function()
    { 
        if(codeType.val() == 273)
        {
            fixedCode.attr('disabled',true);
        }   
    });    
}
```

I want to fetch CodeType dropdown values. Please suggest an appropriate solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically if your DropDownList is bound to field from the Grid model, then you can directly get the value from the Model.

e.g.

```
 function onEdit(e) {
      var codetype = e.model.CodeType;
 }
```